# Modified grub.cfg to start in "text"; can I still launch GUI applications without startx?

Tags: command-line, shell, grub, gui

I found this [simple tutorial](http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/460) for modifying the way my Mint Julia 32 bit OS starts up with a command line only, except my next task is to try and find a way to launch instances of GUI applications without bringing up the entire gnome desktop experience.

In a perfect world, my goal would be to have the gnome desktop environment running in the background, only, there is a terminal session that cannot be closed or minimized, hiding the start menu and desktop. From there you could type in

```
% gnome-keybinding-properties
```

and treat it almost as if I'm using gnome, with all the keyboard shortcuts and media support I'm used to (like, you know, a mouse).

I am looking to blend the best of graphical and command line user interfaces. I like using the command line, but I don't want to lose the things I use most: `google-chrome`, `gedit`, `gcalctool`, `synaptic`. All are good, and are somewhat bound to my hip as a member of Generation Y.

Does anybody know of a good tutorial that can show me how to get this ideal setup on my machine? I'd appreciate it!

Comment: I took away the "text" out of "quiet splash", and am back using Gnome. See my answer below for more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know about LinuxMint, but what is certain:

- You need running an X server in order to run graphical applications
- Most distribution let you switch from console ( cli ) terminals to X terminal via CTRL+ALT+F1-10 keys .

So if you start in cli, you can launch startx in the background ( startx & , or in a screen session ) and then switch between the cli terminal and the X terminal with CTRL+ALT+Fx .
The first time you will have to juggle a bit to find out which F key brings you to the console and which F key is mapped to the X terminal.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I did. It's not perfect, but it emulates my desire well.

1.

```
%gconf-editor
```

And [disable all minimize, maximize, and close system buttons](http://www.addictivetips.com/ubuntu-linux-tips/switch-the-closemaximizeminimize-buttons-to-left-side-in-ubuntu/) through

Apps -> metacity -> general

(among other places. I also [modified my "pane" bar](http://atunu.blogspot.com/2008/02/how-to-hide-taskbar-aka-gnome-panel.html) to show pretty much nothing except the time and the weather, and cleared my desktop of everything).

2. Go to System -> Preferences -> Startup Applications

Add a 'gnome-terminal' command at startup.

3.

```
% sudo apt-get install devilspie
% mkdir ~/.devilspie/
% gedit ~/.devilspie/gnome-terminal.ds
```

And then follow [poster #4's tutorial](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1339097) to put the correct code, replacing

```
(maximize)
```

with

```
(fullscreen undecorate)
```

I still have yet to figure out how to launch a full screen terminal in *all* workspaces across my desktop from the auto-launcher. I have tried throwing a `-t` on my `gnome-terminal` commands, and writing a dedicated `.ds` file for each, but so far nothing has worked. But a `ctrl+alt+t` will get things looking good again.

If anyone finds out how to launch a terminal in all 6 workspaces, I'd appreciate it if you shared that info.